# How can I configure a storage server to provide data delivery on two separate networks?

Tags: networking, storage, nic

I have a storage server with two NICs - each with two ports. The one NIC is 1 GbE, the other is 10 GbE.

I have a 10 GbE switch and have Cat6a running from the two 10 GbE ports into the 10 GbE switch.

I also have a Cat6a cable running from the 1 GbE NIC into one of the main network switches.

I have client machines, most of which need to grab a file here and there from the storage server. They are connected to the main 1GbE switch.

I have a few client machines which need to have high-speed access to the storage server. These are connected to the 10 GbE switch.

These 10 GbE client machines also need to be able to access the main network (which has DNS, DHCP, AD, etc.).

I'm looking for recommendations on how to best configure this setup.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of is the following scenario.

have 2 networks split by vlan or hardware, 1 with your 1gb network - say 10.0.0.0/24 and 1 network for your 10gb traffic - say 10.0.1.0/24

put a router in between the networks - gigabit compatible.

Make sure there is an open connection between the 2 networks, and in your router set your actual gateway as 'next-hop' or default gateway.

split up your client machines by the network requirement, a bunch in the 1g network and a bunch in the 10g. configure those clients to access the server by the right ip, or even hostname if you want to go as far as also splitting up your DNS.

configure those machine to use the router between the networks as default gateway.

This was the 'hard' solution, as for a more simple approach.

have 1 network with all clients, 10gb or 1gb connected to the appropriate switch, and make your file server only accessible on the 10g network interfaces. the 1gb client traffic will be barely noticeable on the whole.